# Plotting a curve from the intersection points of a family of two curves

Tags: plotting

I have two state equations.

```
f1 = 1000. (12 - (1 - u) x2);
f2 = 1000. ((1 - u) x1 - 8/100 x2 );
```

I did two different stream plots for state-variables `x2` and `x1` on the x and y axis respectively. The first stream plot was based on `u = 0` and the second one was based on `u = 1`. Then I superimposed the stream plots using the command `Show[{plt0, plt1}]`.

```
 plt0 = StreamPlot[Flatten[{f1, f2} /. u -> 0], {x2, 0, 30}, {x1, 0, 10},
   StreamPoints -> 500, StreamScale -> Large,
   StreamStyle -> {Blue, Thickness[0.001], Dotted}, Frame -> True,
   FrameLabel -> {Row[{Subscript["x", 2], " - Capacitor  Voltage "}],
     Row[{Subscript["x", 1], " - Inductor  Voltage "}]},
   GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed],
   BaseStyle -> {"Times", 24}, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

```
 plt1 = StreamPlot[Flatten[{f1, f2} /. u -> 1], {x2, 0, 30}, {x1, 0, 10},
    StreamPoints -> 500, StreamScale -> Large,
    StreamStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.001], Dotted}, Frame -> True, 
    FrameLabel -> {Row[{Subscript["x", 2], " - Capacitor  Voltage "}],
      Row[{Subscript["x", 1], " - Inductor  Voltage "}]},
    GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed],
    BaseStyle -> {"Times", 24}, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

```
    Show[{plt0, plt1}]
```

[image]

**Is it possible to draw a curve at the intersection points of the two superimposed streamplots and how?**

Comment: While asking a question it is always better to supply some code snippet that can reproduce or pinpoint the problem you are facing. This spares others from spending time to reformulate a problem for which you may already have a code at hand.

Comment: I'm not really understand your question. What is the curve you want? Or you just want an arbitrary curve which goes through some intersection point in your given plot?

Comment: Virtually every point is the intersection of two stream lines of the vector field at u=0 and u=1.  StreamPlot only gives a sample of all the stream lines.  So a single curve won't go through all the intersection points (of all the stream lines).  Are you looking for something like a wave front?  As I understand StreamPlot, the actual stream lines drawn do not have a regular pattern. A line stops when an area gets too crowded, and vice versa, one starts when an area is too empty.  The intersections of two StreamPlot's are not very telling.

Comment: Actually, for this particualar system of state equations, each line from the first plot uniquely intersects with one and only one line in the second plot. So, by superimposing them, i wanted to draw curve through those unique intersecting points. Any help would be appreaciated.
I was superimposing them through this command
Show[{plt0, plt1}]

Comment: ram, i just posted the picture you get with `Show[plt0,plt1]`.

Comment: Thanks for that. I got the same plot too, but i want to know how to draw a curve that passes through each of those intersecting points.

Comment: Sorry, but there is some fundamental mathematical misunderstanding here. What you want can't be done in a meaningful way, see the comment by @MichaelE2 above. I'm voting to close.

Comment: Oh Well... I can't change your mind, i tried my best in reply to Michael's post what actually i'm looking for. thanks anyway.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand.  Looking at the lines in the combined plot, I see each blue line crossing several red lines, not a unique one.

Comment: Well thanks any way for trying. you can close this thread for the time being if you wish to.

Comment: Long comment part I (1) "Actually, for this particualar system of state equations, each line from the first plot uniquely intersects with one and only one line in the second plot." This is nonsense. (2) "i tried my best in reply to Michael's post what actually i'm looking for." Try again.

Comment: Long comment part II Are you looking for (a) Points where the curves intersect tangentially? (b) Points where the curve families intersect orthogonally? (c) Something else? You have repeatedly referred to "intersection points" but not stated what criteria are used to choose those intersection points. You really should (re)read what @Michael E2 wrote and address that remark in such a way that "uniquely intersects" makes actual sense.

Answer (score 5):

As @MichaelE2 noted in the comments, the lines produced by `StreamPlot` are just "a sample from all the stream lines" and the number of them and the extent of each depend on the option settings as well as finer implementation details. Yet, OP seems to be interested in the intersection of lines in a particular instance of `StreamPlot` output with specific option settings. The following is an attempt to get the intersection points of the lines shown in a graph produced by `StreamPlot` by

1. getting the coordinates of `Line` primitives,
2. producing an interpolating function for each line taking into account the range of its `x` coordinates,
3. solving for the *first* intersection point for each pair of lines from two different stream plots, and
4. adding the points thus obtained to the original stream plots using `Epilog`.

First, the final result (using `StreamPoints -> 10`):

[image]

Some preps:

```
  (* options to be used later *)
 strmPltOpts = {Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {Row[{Subscript["x", 2], " - Capacitor Voltage "}],
   Row[{Subscript["x", 1], " - Inductor Voltage "}]},
  GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed], 
   BaseStyle -> {"Times", 24}, ImageSize -> 500};
 pltOpts = {PlotRange -> {0, 10}, Frame -> True,
   FrameLabel -> {Row[{Subscript["x", 2], " - Capacitor  Voltage "}],
    Row[{Subscript["x", 1], " - Inductor  Voltage "}]},
     GridLines -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
     GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed],
     BaseStyle -> {"Times", 24}, ImageSize -> 500, AspectRatio -> 1};
```

Few helper functions to get the lines, roots, and intersections:

```
  ClearAll[getRootsF, getStrmPltLinesF, getIntrsctnsF];
  getStrmPltLinesF[plt_, x_] :=  Cases[Normal[plt[[1]]], 
  Line[z_] :>  ConditionalExpression[Interpolation[z][x], 
    Min[First@Transpose[z]] <= x <= Max[First@Transpose[z]]], Infinity];
  getRootsF :=  Quiet[If[# ===  Undefined, {}, 
   (soln = FindRoot[ First@#, 
   {x, Sequence @@ {First@#, First@#, Last@#} &@Last[#]}]; 
     {{x /. soln, Last[First[#]] /. soln}, {x /. soln, First[First[#]] /. soln}})]] &;
 getIntrsctnsF := First[Flatten[Quiet[getRootsF /@ #] /. {} -> Sequence[] /.
   {{x_, y_}, {x_, z_}} /; Chop[y + z] != 0 :> 
    Sequence[] /. {_, _?Negative} :> Sequence[], {2}]] &;
```

Step 0: `StreamPlot` both original plots with the option setting `StreamScale->None`:

```
 plt0B = StreamPlot[Flatten[{f1, f2} /. u -> 0], {x2, 0, 30}, {x1, 0, 10},
  StreamPoints -> 10, StreamScale -> None,
  StreamStyle -> {Blue, Thickness[0.001], Dotted}, Evaluate@strmPltOpts];
 plt1B = StreamPlot[Flatten[{f1, f2} /. u -> 1], {x2, 0, 30}, {x1, 0, 10},
 StreamPoints -> 10, StreamScale -> None, 
  StreamStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.001], Dotted},  Evaluate@strmPltOpts];
 Show[{plt0B, plt1B}]
```

[image]

Steps 1 and 2: Use the helper function `getStrmPltLinesF[strmplt, x]` to get an interpolating function for each line in `strmplt`. Here is how these interpolating functions look when used in `Plot`:

```
 plt0Ba = Quiet@ Plot[Evaluate@getStrmPltLinesF[plt0B, x], {x, 0, 30}, 
    ColorFunction -> "LakeColors", Evaluate[pltOpts]];
 plt1Bb = Quiet@ Plot[Evaluate@getStrmPltLinesF[plt1B, x], {x, 0, 30}, 
    ColorFunction -> "SolarColors", Evaluate[pltOpts]];
 Show[{plt0Ba, plt1Bb}]
```

[image]

Step 3: get the points of intersection for every pair of lines using the helper function `getIntrsctnsF`:

```
 pairwiseDiffs = Join @@ Outer[Subtract, getStrmPltLinesF[plt0B, x], 
   getStrmPltLinesF[plt1B, x]];
 intrsctnPoints = getIntrsctnsF@pairwiseDiffs;
```

Last step: change the options settings back to the original and add the intersection points using Epilog to one of the two original stream plots:

```
 plt0Bfinal = StreamPlot[Flatten[{f1, f2} /. u -> 0], {x2, 0, 30}, {x1, 0, 10},
  StreamPoints -> 10, StreamScale -> Large, 
  StreamStyle -> {Blue, Thickness[0.001], Dotted},  Evaluate@strmPltOpts, 
  Epilog -> {Green, PointSize[.02], Point[intrsctnPoints]}];
 plt1Bfinal = StreamPlot[Flatten[{f1, f2} /. u -> 1], {x2, 0, 30}, {x1, 0, 10},
   StreamPoints -> 10, StreamScale -> Large, 
   StreamStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.001], Dotted}, Evaluate@strmPltOpts];
 Show[{plt0Bfinal, plt1Bfinal}]
```

to get the first picture above.

Comment: +1 for the effort.   By the way, welcome to the 20K club! :-)

Comment: @Mr.W thank you for the vote and the welcome.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr Wizard. I'll take a look. I cam work with this right now.

Answer (score 4):

This is intended as a complement to kguler's response. I add to those stream plots the curves where intersections are parallel and orthogonal respectively.

```
x[u_, x1_, x2_] := 1000* (12 - (1 - u) x2)
y[u_, x1_, x2_] := 1000*((1 - u) x1 - 8/100 x2)
```

Compute the implicit forms of the parallel and perpendicularly intersecting point sets (both are curves).

```
perppoly = {x[0, x1, x2], y[0, x1, x2]}.{x[1, x1, x2], 
   y[1, x1, x2]}

(* 12000000 (12 - x2) - 80000 (x1 - (2 x2)/25) x2 *)

parapoly = 
 First[GroebnerBasis[
   Thread[{x[0, x1, x2], y[0, x1, x2]} - 
     lambda*{x[1, x1, x2], y[1, x1, x2]}], lambda]]

(* -150 x1 + x2^2 *)
```

Create the plots.

```
cperp = ContourPlot[{x[0, x1, x2], y[0, x1, x2]}.{x[1, x1, x2], 
      y[1, x1, x2]} == 0, {x2, 0, 30}, {x1, 0, 10}, 
   ContourStyle -> {Thick, Green, Dashed}];

cparal = ContourPlot[parapoly == 0, {x2, 0, 30}, {x1, 0, 10}, 
   ContourStyle -> {Thick, Black, Dotted}];
```

Now show the whole thing.

```
Show[plt0, plt1, cperp, cparal]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a ton Mr Wizard and Daniel and all others who helped out. I think the black dotted curve is what i was looking for. this Surely helps. And i sincerely apologize if my questions were confusing but my understanding of mathematica is very basic and so i probably couldn't clarify enough.