# How to plot an Eddington-Finkelstein diagram

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I need to plot the same thing as what is shown on the third picture of the site below (sorry, I'm unable to poste that picture here) :

http://ion.uwinnipeg.ca/~vincent/4500.6-001/Cosmology/Black_Holes.htm

Notice the oblique axis.  How can we do that ?

Here's the code which draws some of the curves (outgoing radiation curves),

```
NullCurve[n_] := NDSolve[{
    u'[r] == 2/(1 - 1/r),
    u[4] == 2n
    }, {u}, {r, 1, 4},
    Method -> Automatic,
    MaxSteps -> 100000
]

PhotonCurve[n_] := Plot[Evaluate[u[r] /. NullCurve[n]],
    {r, 0, 4},
    PlotStyle -> {Thick, RGBColor[0.20, 0.50, 0.90]}
]

Show[{
    Table[PhotonCurve[n], {n, -2, 8}]
    },
    PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {-4, 4}},
    AspectRatio -> 2,
    Frame -> True,
    Ticks -> True,
    Axes -> True,
    AxesOrigin -> {1, 10},
    AxesStyle -> GrayLevel[0.5],
    GridLines -> Automatic,
    GridLinesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.5], Dotted],
    FrameLabel -> {
        Style[r/(2 G M), Italic, FontSize -> 12],
        Style[u/(2 G M), Italic, FontSize -> 12]
    },
    RotateLabel -> False,
    ImageSize -> 400
]
```

In the final project, a mass function $M(u)$ may be added to the differential equation that is numerically solved in the code above :

```
u'[r] == 2/(1 - M[u]/r)
```

So I can't use the analytical solution $u(r)$ shown on the refered web page.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62581/convert-coordinates-from-cartesian-system-to-non-orthogonal-axes

Comment: See [Plotting a curve from the intersection points of a family of two curves](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16585/plotting-a-curve-from-the-intersection-points-of-a-family-of-two-curves/16649#16649)

Answer (score 3):

I will use Eq. 22.7 of your reference

$ v = 2 r + 4 m \ln(|r - 2 m|) + B$

The obliques are, I guess is given by $v=-u$. For scaling I am considering $u=2mr$.

```
m = 1/2;
Show[ContourPlot[Evaluate@Table[ v == 2 r + 4 m Log[Abs[r - 2 m]] + n, 
{n, -5, 5}], {r,0,4 m}, {v,-3m,3m}, ContourStyle -> Blue, AspectRatio -> 3/2], 
ContourPlot[Evaluate@Table[v == -2 m r + n, {n, -5, 5}],
{r, 0, 4 m}, {v, -3 m, 3 m}, ContourStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

**Numerical solution of differential equation**

As you know that there is a singularity at `r=2m`. So You can't have a single solution for $0<r<\infty$. So you have to calculate them separately for `r<2m` and `r>2m` with proper boundary condition in that region.

```
edfin[m_, r_, n_] := Module[{ul, ur, x, d, u},
d = 0.001; 
ul = u /. NDSolve[{u'[x] == 2 x/(x-2 m), u[0] == 0 + n}, {u}, {x, d,2 m-d}][[1]];
ur = u /. NDSolve[{u'[x] == 2 x/(x-2 m), u[4 m]==4 + n},{u},{x,2 m+d, 10 m}][[1]];
Piecewise[{{ul, 0 < r < 2 m}, {ur, r > 2 m}}]][r]

Plot[edfin[1/2, r, 0], {r, 0, 4}]
```

[image]

```
efcord=Plot[Table[edfin[1/2, r, n], {n, -3, 3}], {r, 0.001, 2}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {-2, 2}, AspectRatio -> 2, Axes -> False];
Show[efcord, Plot[Table[-x + n, {n, -3, 3}], {x, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

I avoided `r=0` because it is a true singularity.

Comment: The straight lines should be at 45 degrees, exactly.

Comment: Well, I choose `m=1/2` so it is 45 degree. I am safe here :)

Comment: Oops, I didn't noticed that the axes aren't scaled the same on your picture.  You should add AspectRatio -> proper value.

Comment: The problem with your method is that it's using the analytical solution of a differential equation.  For a general case, the equation may be using a Mass function $M(u)$ (Vaidya spacetime), so a numerical solution is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I may have found a nice way.  However, I think the output is a bit ugly.  Here's the working code :

```
NullCurve1[n_] := NDSolve[{
    u'[r] == 2/(1 - 1/r),
    u[0] == 2 n

    }, {u}, {r, 0, 1},
    Method -> Automatic,
    MaxSteps -> 100000
]

NullCurve2[n_] := NDSolve[{
    u'[r] == 2/(1 - 1/r), 
    u[5] == 2 n

    }, {u}, {r, 1, 10},
    Method -> Automatic,
    MaxSteps -> 100000
]

PhotonCurve1[n_] := ParametricPlot[
    Evaluate[{r, u[r] - r}/.NullCurve1[n]],
    {r, 0, 1},
    PlotStyle -> {Thick, RGBColor[0.40, 0.60, 0.40]}
]

PhotonCurve2[n_] := ParametricPlot[
    Evaluate[{r, u[r] - r} /.NullCurve2[n]],
    {r, 0, 10},
    PlotStyle -> {Thick, RGBColor[0.60, 0.40, 0.40]}
]

PhotonCurve3[n_] := ParametricPlot[
    {r, 2 n - r},
    {r, 0, 10},
    PlotStyle -> {Thick, RGBColor[0.40, 0.40, 0.60]}
]

Show[{
    Table[PhotonCurve1[n], {n, -2, 4}],
    Table[PhotonCurve2[n], {n, 0, 9}],
    Table[PhotonCurve3[n], {n, -2, 5}]
    },
    PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {-5, 5}},
    PlotRangeClipping -> True,
    AspectRatio -> 2,
    Frame -> True,
    FrameTicks -> None,
    Axes -> True,
    AxesOrigin -> {1, 10},
    AxesStyle -> GrayLevel[0.5],
    GridLines -> None,
    GridLinesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.5], Dotted],
    FrameLabel -> {
        Style[r/(2 G M), Italic, FontSize -> 12],
        Style[(u + r)/(2 G M), Italic, FontSize -> 12]
    },
    RotateLabel -> False,
    ImageSize -> 400
]
```

Here's a preview of what that code is doing :

[image: Eddington-Finkelstein diagram]